# Why does ArcMap show quantities for values that are not in attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fields-attributes

I've joined a csv file of values (0-100) (created in Excel), with local authority boundaries for the UK in ArcMap 10.1. I want to display the percentage of these areas not receiving 3G mobile coverage.

I've gone into properties and then selected quantities. I've selected the data I want to display and it displays huge values which are not in either the original data set or in the attributes table. Why is this? Here is a screen shot (note the range):

[image: Screen grab 1]

When I go into the attributes table for the selected variable ('t') and then sort descending, the largest value is 99. Why does it think there are values up to 1965621253?

[image: Screen grab 2]

I've not managed to find an answer online but so far I've:

1. Checked that Excel isn't adding on extra values (I copied and pasted just the values numerous times)
2. Generated a new csv file
3. Tried to join the data numerous times to see if this made a difference.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Arcmap and do it all over again? Also, what if you look at the csv table from within Armap/catalog? It's not a decimal separator mixup?

Comment: I have found that joined tables sometimes confuse ArcMap, as will null values.  Workarounds include removing and redoing the join, doing the join in a new project and symbolizing it there before adding that to the original project, and exporting to a new feature class for symbolizing.

Comment: I would try adding a field and calculating it to equal "t". Then, remove the join and try to symbolize it off of the new field.  Like @johns said, joined tables behave strangely sometimes.

Comment: I tried restarting Arcmap - same problem. I checked that there are no null values in the data set. I tried making a new project and repeating the join - same problem. I exported the shape files and did the join again - same problem. I finally tried to make a new field equal to the field I'm trying to symbolise. Still the same problem I'm afraid. Any other ideas?

Comment: What is the data type of the t field in ArcMap? Both as part of a Join and if you export the join result to a separate file? Is there any kind of numeric formatting on the field that might be disguising the true values? In attribute table right-click field heading and you can find the answer to both of these - it will tell you the type and you can click the ... `numeric` button to check that. Can you post files (or excerpts)/sources so we can try to duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classes seem to contain the values you want to display but have also ultra high ones. 
I have not a exact solution to your problem but some hints you could try.

- Add the .csv file to ArcMap and export it as .dbf before joining. Add the .dbf to your workspace and try the join with this file
- Alternatively open the .dbf files in excel and check if these high values
  occur in the table.
- There could be a problem with the delimiter as well. As far as I know the standard delimiter of excel is different to the one of ArcMap. You could try to replace these delimiters with Notepad++ or similar before adding the .csv to ArcMap

Comment: Also try putting importing the CSV into a .gdb table.  I find ArcMap works super well with these tables, so I use them a lot when I don't need to view or change them with other software.  Also, it's improved, but Excel + ArcMap + joins is sometimes a little much to ask...

Comment: Having opened the file in Notepad I found a null value that I hadn't seen in Excel. The join then worked fine and the problem was solved. Thanks for the help.